# Кастомизация темы Angular Material 9.2.4

Tags: angular2, angular, scss, angular-material

Друзья, пытаюсь кастомизировать тему для Angular Material. Кажется делаю все согласно официальному [гайду](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

```css
@import "~@angular/material/theming";

$md-editor: (
  50: #e4f6ff,
  100: #bce9ff,
  200: #8fdbff,
  300: #62ccff,
  400: #41c1ff,
  500: #1fb6ff,
  600: #1bafff,
  700: #17a6ff,
  800: #129eff,
  900: #0a8eff,
  A100: #ffffff,
  A200: #f5faff,
  A400: #c2e0ff,
  A700: #a8d4ff,
  contrast: (
    50: #000000,
    100: #000000,
    200: #000000,
    300: #000000,
    400: #000000,
    500: #000000,
    600: #000000,
    700: #000000,
    800: #ffffff,
    900: #ffffff,
    A100: #000000,
    A200: #000000,
    A400: #000000,
    A700: #000000,
  ),
);

$template-editor-primary: mat-palette($md-editor);
$template-editor-accent: mat-palette($md-editor, A200, A100, A400);
$template-editor-warn: mat-palette($md-editor);
$template-editor-theme: mat-light-theme($template-editor-primary, $template-editor-accent, $template-editor-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($template-editor-theme);
@include mat-core();
```

Создал вот такой файл theme.scss, добавил его в angular.json, но наблюдаю следующую ситуацию - что то переопределяет мои цвета на mat-deep-purple.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит я не понимаю, по коду ни каких других определений темы нет.
У кого нибудь есть какие нибудь варианты или идеи? Спасибо

Comment: Как оказалась видимо если компонент из другого модуля тоже использует Material, то он может пдобавить дополнительные стили на страницу и повлиять на цвеат в теме.

Я пока не нашел решения проблемы, но по крайней мере теперь понятно в чем она сотоит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью описанной в документации возможности [**Multiple themes**](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

Создал новый класс в котором вызвал angular-material-theme. Добавил этот класс для контейнера приложения и overlay.

```
 // theme.scss
.my-example-theme {
    @include angular-material-theme($my-theme-variable);
 }
```